# Android TCP server recieves all data on application exit

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm having the following TCP client code:

```
public static void register(InetAddress ip, int port, String name) {
     try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
        send("reg:" + name);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void send(String str) {
    try {
        String sentence = str;
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("CONNECT", e.getMessage());
    }

   }
```

They both are called in onClicks and i know that for sure.
I also have the following Server code:

```
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
String clientSentence;
  ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9876);
  while (true) {
 Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
 BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
   new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
   DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
   connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
 outToClient.writeBytes("msg: Hello! kalin pedro");
}
}
```

When trying to send data to the server i don't get an exception, i also know that I'm connected to it because the application is crashing when i terminate the server application. The problem is that the server doesn't receive anything until i terminate the client application. Everything that i have tried to send until that moment is all received from the server at once. I looked at the network activity tab provided by Android Studio and there is a change when sending data, the server just doesn't receive it(or at least i don't see it receive it) until i terminate the client application.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the stream?

Comment: You should be closing the output stream to indicate that the data is finished. Otherwise the server just thinks that the client is waiting to send more data to it.

Comment: Don't use a new `DataOutputStream` or any other reader, writer, or stream per send or receive. Use the same ones for the life of the socket.